# Playwright python test for value in outbound request URL

Tags: pytest, playwright, playwright-python

I'm using Playwright Python (and pytest-playwright) for some testing of my site. The page I'm testing makes calls to an analytics partner (like Google Analytics) but with just a `GET` request and a long query string which has the analytics data.

I'd like to verify that a certain value, e.g. `foo=bar`, is in the call to the analytics partner. For this example, I'll use `analytics.example.com`.

I have this code in my test:

```py
import re
r = re.compile('https://analytics.example.com/.*foo=bar.*')
with page.expect_request(r, timeout=15000) as analytics_call:
    print('got expected analytics call')
```

When I run the test, I see the "got expected analytics call" but the test fails with a timeout message:

`playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 15000ms exceeded while waiting for event "request"`

I also considered using `page.on("request", my_event_handler)` and the event handler function is called... but then I'm not sure how to pass or fail the test based on what the event handler does.

How would one write a test that tests for a value in an outbound request?

Answer (score 0):

`page.expect_*` return context managers that intend for you to trigger the events you're looking for within the `with` statement. For example:

```py
    r = re.compile('http://example.com/.*foo=bar.*')
    with page.expect_request(r, timeout=15000) as analytics_call:
        page.goto('http://example.com/?foo=bar') # this will trigger the request we're expecting
```

Everything in the `with` block is run immediately, it's only upon trying to exit the scope of that block that the condition is waited for (if it's not already fulfilled).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of how the `expect_*` context managers work. They aren’t what I need. 

Any ideas of how I can _test_ the value of the query parameter of the outbound request.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to verify that a certain query string parameter was set, this approach would work fine.

Comment: I'm not following – where's the test here? How would I assert something that would pass or fail? I'm not trying to execute a new action/path when this page is requested, just verifying that the expected query parameter(s) exist

Comment: You need to "record" any requests made before you want to see if they occured. In this example, we use expect_...(and therefore record requests) before then going to a URL that triggers this request.

If the request isn't seen within the timeout, this will raise a TimeoutError and the tests will fail.